# I2C doesn't work on Raspberry Pi 3 with Android Things

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, i2c, android-things

How to detect the problem? I'm trying to find one device on I2C bus. It found bus, but doesn't found any device. I have two main board, two different devices (AM2321 and converter I2C->3wire), and tried them in different combinations. I do something wrong, but can not understand, what exactly.

```
    val bus = manager.i2cBusList.first() // in my device one and only one bus now
    Log.d("happy", "bus: $bus")

    val devices = (0..127).filter { address ->
        manager.openI2cDevice(bus, address).use { device ->
            try {
                device.write(ByteArray(1), 1)
                true
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                false
            }
        }
    }

    if (devices.isEmpty()) {
        Log.d("happy", "no devices")
    } else {
        devices.forEach { address ->
            Log.d("happy", "device $address")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With Android Things DP 6 you can use [PIO CLI Tool](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/pio-cli.html#I2C) to detect issue:

> ```
> pio i2c name address subcommand [arg]
>
> name is the name of a valid I2C bus.
>
> address is the address of an I2C device.
>
> subcommand can be one of the following:
> Subcommand    Description
> read-raw size     Read size bytes from device.
> read-reg-byte reg     Read a byte from reg.
> read-reg-word reg     Read a word (2 bytes) from reg.
> read-reg-buffer reg size  Read size bytes from reg.
> write-raw val [val ...]   Write val to device.
> write-reg-byte reg val    Write byte val to reg.
> write-reg-word reg val    Write word val to reg.
> write-reg-buffer reg val [val ...]    Write val to reg.
> ```
>
> Example
>
> ```
> $ pio i2c I2C1 0x10 write-reg-byte 0x20 0x40
> $ pio i2c I2C1 0x12 read-reg-byte 0x24 0x7F
> ```

Also take a look at [this](https://proandroiddev.com/android-things-analog-i-o-and-pwm-spi-i%C2%B2c-tutorial-with-the-raspberry-pi-5bbc957099da) and [that](http://android.geek.nz/i2c-with-android-things-part-1/) tutorials.

Comment: Thank you. Very good resources, but still doesn't work for me. 'pio' returns the same error as my code. And there is no scanner out of the box. Seems like problem with hardware, but there is no ideas how to detect it. Will setup native linux and try from there.

Comment: I have definitely used I2C and it worked fine. Can you try with other components? Maybe the I2C pin is broken?

Comment: If " 'pio' returns the same error as my code" - there is no issue with your code. May be issue is in wire connection, or as [shalafi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/539171/shalafi) wrote I2C pin is broken.